# Handling Media Storage Failure

Tags: android, scoped-storage

So basically i'm migrating my app to Scoped Storage.
I'm facing issue while capturing image in android version 10.

**(it's working fine with android version 11).**

**System Logs**

```
E/CAM_FatalErrorHandler: Handling Media Storage Failure:
    java.lang.Exception
        at d.b.a.Rb.Ge(SourceFile:1)
        at d.b.a.cf.onError(SourceFile:1)
        at d.b.a.cf.av(SourceFile:12)
        at d.b.a.De.onClick(SourceFile:1)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27340)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
2021-04-22 19:43:08.303 3031-3031/? E/CAM_CameraUtil: Show fatal error dialog
```

Camera Intent Method :

```
private static Intent getLaunchCameraIntent(Context context, String applicationId, LaunchCameraCallback callback)
            throws IOException {
        File externalStoragePublicDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        String mediaCapturePath = externalStoragePublicDirectory + File.separator + "Camera" + File.separator + "dd-" + System
                .currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = new File(mediaCapturePath).getParentFile();
        if (directory == null || (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs())) {
            try {
                throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created: " + mediaCapturePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(e);
                throw e;
            }
        }

        Uri fileUri;
        try {
            fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, applicationId + ".provider", new File(mediaCapturePath));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e("Cannot access the file planned to store the new media", e);
            throw new IOException("Cannot access the file planned to store the new media");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("Cannot access the file planned to store the new media - " +
                    "FileProvider.getUriForFile cannot find a valid provider for the authority: " + applicationId + ".provider", e);
            throw new IOException("Cannot access the file planned to store the new media");
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onMediaCapturePathReady(mediaCapturePath);
        }
        return intent;
    }
```

**Solutions tried till now:**

1. Changing `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` to `context.getExternalFilesDir` (Not Worked).
2. Changing `File(mediaCapturePath).getParentFile();` to `File(context.context.getCacheDir(),getmediaCapturePath).getParentFile();` (Not Worked).
3. Tried debugging but callback is not received from camera app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you hear of requestion legacy external storage in application tag of manifest file? But even without that getExternalFilesDir() should work.

Comment: @blackapps Yeah, but they have removed the support requestion legacy now, sent the warning on play console.

Comment: see if this helps : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage  &  https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/scoped-storage-in-android-10-android-11-28d58d989f3c

Comment: `I'm facing issue ` Which issue? And which statement causes it?

Comment: @blackapps issue is while capturing image, and none of the statement is throwing the exception, Logs are from camera app. Not receiving any result from camera app.

Comment: @pravingaikwad07 tried using getExternalFilesDir() not worked.

Comment: So no issue in your code but an issue with the camera app. Why didnt you tell so rigth at the start? And try other camera apps.

Comment: @blackapps tried with other android 10 devices, still same error.

Comment: Error : Failed to save Photo

Comment: @pravingaikwad07 was able to fix this using getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES). Place it as an answer i'll accept it